# How to submit a new step to a running EMR cluster in java sdk v2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, aws-java-sdk-2.x

I am trying to submit a HadoopJarStep to a running EMR cluster with the java sdk v2. From reading the api docs / examples I can't seem to figure out how to reference a running cluster instead of spinning up a new one.

Can anyone point me to the correct builder method to specify an existing cluster to submit to? The Scala code I have so far:

```
val emr = EmrClient
  .builder()
  .build()       

val stepArgs = Seq("foo", "bar", "baz")

val jarStepConfig = HadoopJarStepConfig.builder()
      .jar("s3://reveal-ci/deploy/emr/visit-etl.jar")
      .args(stepArgs: _*)
      .mainClass("com.revealmobile.visit.etl.Application")
      .build()

val stepConfig = Seq(
      StepConfig.builder()
      .hadoopJarStep(jarStepConfig)
      .build()
    ).asJavaCollection

val stepRequest = AddJobFlowStepsRequest.builder()
      .steps(stepConfig)
      .jobFlowId("JOB FLOW ID")
      .build()

val result = Try(emr.addJobFlowSteps(stepRequest)) // I never specified which cluster?

result match {
      case Success(_) => info("The step was added successfully")
      case Failure(exception) =>
        error(exception.getMessage)
        throw (exception)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out that terminology is a bit different between CLI and SDK. cluster == job flow in this case so I needed to use this to point to the correct cluster:

```
val stepRequest = AddJobFlowStepsRequest.builder()
      .steps(stepConfig)
      .jobFlowId("JOB FLOW ID") //here 
      .build()
```